# Hole pattern in model when moving in sculpt mode

Tags: 3d-view, sculpting

this is not the first time this is occuring to me and I wonder if it might lead to problems further down the road. I created a metaball as I mostly do when starting to sculpt and as soon as I am moving the view in the viewport I get this pattern, as to be seen in the picture. But it disappears the second as I let go the MMB.

Any idea why this happens and if this could be a problem?

Thanks for reading. [image]

Answer (score 1):

2.8b still has a lot of draw issues, it probably won't affect your mesh. You can report bugs here https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/